# AJAX response need to be converted to blob

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blob

I have written ajax code to set request headers in `url` and convert that to a blob and pass to a function `showFile (blob);` The `blob` is then processed and downloaded in pdf format
The `blob` value obtained in the code is coming as `undefined`. Can someone please help me to resolve the issue`

```
   var resolved = function (url) {
        var showFile = function (blob) {
            var newBlob = new Blob([blob], {type:"application/pdf"})                   
            const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = data;
            link.download = options.name;
            link.click();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
            }, 100)
        }
        var jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
        var headerObj = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + jwtToken}

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        $.ajax({
            dataType:'blob',
            type:'GET',
            url:url
        }).done(function(blob){
            showFile(blob); 
        });
    };
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: JQuery 3.1.1 version

Answer (score 5):

If you need a blob response from jQuery ajax, set the `responseType` field of `xhrFields` to `blob`. 
Since the response will be a blob you don't have to create one.
Also, did you forget to add your auth header to the request?

```
   var resolved = function (url) {
        var showFile = function (blob) {                 
            const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = data;
            link.download = options.name;
            link.click();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
            }, 100)
        }
        var jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
        var headerObj = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + jwtToken}

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        $.ajax({
            xhrFields: {
               responseType: 'blob' 
            }
            headers: headerObj, 
            type:'GET',
            url:url
        }).done(function(blob){
            showFile(blob); 
        });
    };
```