# Print generated pdf (with tcpdf) in an iframe after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, tcpdf

I'm using tcpdf to create pdf files with ajax call that send some data to pdf script for generating the pdf, then i would like to pass the pdf to iframe src

My tcpdf pdf creation ; last lines

```
    $p = header ("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    echo $pdf->Output('', 'S');
```

Ajax call

```
 var form = $("#submiEditCanevaForm");
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);

                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                $('#pdf_file_edit').attr("src", downloadUrl);


   
            }


        });
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: I'm trying to print the pdf generated in success function in my iframe ( id = pdf_file_edit ). I use tcpdf to generate the pdf

Comment: So, your code is working fine? You only need to print your iframe?

Comment: No it doesn't works the pdf is well generated but it's not printed on iframe. I jus added the screenshot. This message is asking for a password

Comment: That's weird... Did you encrypt the PDF? Did you use TCPDF `SetProtection` method?

Comment: No i didn't set protection for the file. The same pdf script is opening the pdf file if i set the url directly in src iframe attribute.  Now cause i wanna make same changes in content of pdf i have to use an ajax call to make the changes and then print the result again in same iframe

Comment: First I would try to Output the PDF as a file ('F' parameter), then the AJAX callback only needs to update the iframe src to the new file. If that works, then that means the issue comes from the Blob part.

Comment: Yes this is working . Maybe i will save the pdf first and then print it as you said . Thank you

Comment: OK good! I found that you'll need to "*set the responseType field of xhrFields to blob*" for it to work. Source here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188750/ajax-response-need-to-be-converted-to-blob